# Can I somehow combine SDL and Android Java UI elements?

Tags: android, sdl

I have an application which renders video in, say, 3 areas of the screen. In each area it renders a different video.

What I am doing is: I'm decoding the frames for all the 3 videos using NDK then pass the  frames as bitmaps up to Java and render those bitmaps in 3 different SurfaceViews on the screen.

It works but I have heard one should be able to do a faster rendering using SDL.

Now, all the SDL for Android examples they seem to render in a single window - the entire screen. But I need rendering in specific places on my screens as I also have some Java UI elements on the screen.

So, can I somehow use SDL but render in specific screen areas keeping other areas for Java UI controls and other things?